# Print a page in IE -> canvas not printing

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, canvas, printing

I have a page with some canvas. By using the javascript trick the Canvas is displaying in IE browser.

If i go File-> Print Preview also it is showing the canvas correctly. But when i print it, i am getting "No canvas support".

Is there anything to do with code or browser settings?

Comment: What IE version and what "javascript trick"?

Comment: I am using IE 8. We are using RGraph.net's product (http://www.rgraph.net/) . They gave a library called excanvas.js, if we import that file the canvas will work in IE.